# How can I draw multiple circles through touch listening?

Tags: android, graphics, touch

I am trying to let the user draw multiple circles on my imageview, using touch. So far I 've managed to draw just one at a time. I understand that I have to store the touch points and redraw every circle after calling invalidate(), but have not figured a way to do it.

Here is my code, I would really appreciate if someone could point out what I have to add/change or give any advice on how to implement this:

```
public class ImageView1 extends ImageView {

public int x;
public int y;

ImageView1 img = (ImageView1) findViewById (R.id.imageView1);


    public ImageView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs); 
       setFocusable(true);

    } 

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

       x = (int) event.getX();
       y = (int) event.getY();


    return true;
    }

    @Override   
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
       super.onDraw(canvas);
       Paint p = new Paint();

   p.setAntiAlias(true);
   p.setColor(Color.RED);
   p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
   p.setStrokeWidth(1);

   canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 20, p);
       invalidate();
}

 }
```

Comment: When do you want to draw the circles, when the user: puts their finger down, moves around, or lifts up? (Or all of them?)

Comment: I believe when the user puts their finger down

Answer (score 1):

I'm usually gathering pointer position information into `SparseArray` with pointer ID as a key;

```
private SparseArray<PointF> mPointers = new SparseArray<PointF>();

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    switch (me.getActionMasked()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
        int ai = me.getActionIndex();
        PointF pt = new PointF(me.getX(ai), me.getY(ai));
        mPointers.put(me.getPointerId(ai), pt);
        return true;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        int pid = me.getPointerId(me.getActionIndex());
        mPointers.remove(pid);
        return true;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        for (int i = 0; i < me.getPointerCount(); ++i) {
            PointF pt = mPointers.get(me.getPointerId(i));
            pt.set(me.getX(i), me.getY(i));
        }
        return true;
    }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then for rendering separate touch points you can iterate over `mPointers` values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but as a rookie, I am not quite familiar with Sparse Arrays. I' ll see what I can learn though.